# Multiprocessing of for nested loops

Tags: python, parallel-processing, nested, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I am trying to excute the following code, to save the list data_set_N at the end.

```
import re
data_set_N=[]    
for i_1 in list(range(10))+list("+-"):
    for i_2 in list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]:
        for i_3 in list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]:
            for i_4 in list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]:
                for i_5 in list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]:
                    for i_6 in list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]:
                        for i_7 in list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]:
                            for i_8 in list(range(10)):
                                try :
                                    value= str(i_1)+str(i_2)+str(i_3)+str(i_4)+str(i_5)+str(i_6)+str(i_7)+str(i_8)
                                    valuev=re.sub(r'\b0+(?!\b)', '', value)
                                    evaluation = eval(valuev)
                                    if type(evaluation) == type(True) and evaluation and "//" not in value:
                                        data_set_N.append(value)

                                except:
                                    continue
print(len(data_set_N))
```

The problem is that it will take more than 50 hours, for the the first i_1 it took 4.5 hours.
To get `data_set_N` faster I wanted to use multiprocessing. The idea was to use something like this :

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import itertools    
import re

def add_value(data_set_N,paramlist):
    #I am not sure if this function is well defined
    try 
        i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4 = paramlist[0],paramlist[1],paramlist[2],paramlist[3]
        i_5,i_6,i_7,i_8 = paramlist[4],paramlist[5],paramlist[6],paramlist[7]
        value = str(i_1)+str(i_2)+str(i_3)+str(i_4)+str(i_5)+str(i_6)+str(i_7)+str(i_8)
        valuev =re.sub(r'\b0+(?!\b)', '', value)
        evaluation = eval(valuev)
        if type(evaluation) == type(True) and evaluation and "//" not in value:
            data_set_N.append(value)

    except:
        return     
        
        
data_set_N = [] 
#Generate values for each parameter
I_1 = list(range(10))+list("+-")
I_2 = list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]
I_3 = list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]
I_4 = list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]
I_5 = list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]
I_6 = list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]
I_7 = list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]
I_8 = list(range(10))
paramlist = list(itertools.product(I_1,I_2,I_3,I_4,I_5,I_6,I_7,I_8))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Manager() as manager:
        data_set_N = manager.list()  # <-- can be shared between processes.
        processes = []

        for i in range(10): #os.cpu_count() - 2 =10 , this range can be changed
            p = Process(target=add_value, args=(data_set_N,paramlist))  # Passing the list
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)

        for p in processes:
            pool.close()
            pool.join()

        data_set_N = list(data_set_N) #the final list
```

The problem here is with `paramlist` that causes a `MemoryError` (because its size is 12x15^6x10).

Is there a way to use multiprocessing to execute the code faster (around 10 hours), while avoiding memory problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is:

1. Use a multiprocessing pool.
2. Keep your basic code as is except with 7 nested loops (the seven inner loops) and each submitted task is processing a value from the `i_1` list.
3. Move the inexpensive `'//' in value` check immediately after `value` is evaluated and possibly avoid doing a needless regular expression substitution and call to the `eval` function.

This will use up to 12 cores (the length of the `i_1` list) if your computer has them. If your computer has 12 cores *and* they are all physical cores *and* nothing else is running, I would expect the execution time to be reduced by a factor of 12. If you have 6 physical and 6 logical cores and other processes are running, then the execution time will clearly not be reduced by a factor of 12 (I cannot predict by how much). But this is the simplest way of solving your memory issues.

If you had many more cores than 12, then you could define `process_value` to have the 6 inner most loops and use method `starmap` (each element of the `iterable` will be a tuple and `process_value` will now have two arguments in addition to the managed list, `i_1` and `i_2`) with the *iterable* argument being the product of `i_1` list and `i_2` list.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, cpu_count
from functools import partial
import re


def process_value(data_set_N, i_1):
    for i_2 in list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]:
        for i_3 in list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]:
            for i_4 in list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]:
                for i_5 in list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]:
                    for i_6 in list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]:
                        for i_7 in list(range(10))+list("+-*/")+["=="]:
                            for i_8 in list(range(10)):
                                try:
                                    value = str(i_1)+str(i_2)+str(i_3)+str(i_4)+str(i_5)+str(i_6)+str(i_7)+str(i_8)
                                    if '//' in value:
                                        continue
                                    valuev = re.sub(r'\b0+(?!\b)', '', value)
                                    evaluation = eval(valuev)
                                    if type(evaluation) == type(True) and evaluation:
                                        data_set_N.append(value)
                                except:
                                    continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        data_set_N = manager.list()
        # The iterable is the i_1 list:
        i_1_list = list(range(10))+list("+-")
        POOL_SIZE = min(cpu_count(), len(i_1_list))
        pool = Pool(POOL_SIZE)
        pool.map(partial(process_value, data_set_N), i_1_list)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print(len(data_set_N))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, perfect!  I would just add `data_set_N=list(data_set_N)` after `pool.join()`